# Link Apple Health Data to firebase user

Tags: ios, firebase, swiftui, healthkit

I'm building a basic SwiftUI app which reads user steps data from HealthKit and stores the steps count to linked firebase Firestore database.
My app use Firebase email/password authentication. I want to somehow read user's Apple ID linked with the health store and I want to store it in my firebase database. This is to ensure if user logs in from another device, data from other health store linked to another device don't mix with user's own data already stored in firebase.
So logically I need to keep track of users Apple ID to match that on new device with the one user provided initially.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Apple unfortunately won't allow you to get the Apple ID for the user, as this would be a privacy concern if any app could access that information. In general, a unique identifier that stays the same between uninstalling and reinstalling the app for this specific purpose doesn't really exist. Instead, I would just store your own unique ID in the NSUserDefaults the first time your app starts.

Comment: Even if you could get the Apple ID it wouldn't always help you; for example, for historical reasons my Apple  id is a different email address to my commonly used email

Comment: Thanks all, I think I can use below and change the logic to identify the user device.  UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor